# How do I return a value to 2 decimal places from my SQL calculation?

Tags: sql, function

I have the follow sql statement and i want to return the value in "percent_change" to 2 decimal places

```sql
SELECT
  station_name,
  routes,
  ridership_2013,
  ridership_2014,
  ridership_2014 - ridership_2013 AS change_2013_raw,
  ((ridership_2014 - ridership_2013)/ ridership_2013)*100 AS Percent_Change,
FROM
  bigquery-public-data.new_york_subway.subway_ridership_2013_present
WHERE
  ridership_2013 <>0 OR ridership_2014 <>0
```

I do not know when to add my roundup statement.

Comment: It depends on your DBMS, and the functions it allows in its environment. You can try using `ROUND(<your_computed_val>, 2)` to do that.

Comment: Please read the [TAG Description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) of the `sql` tag you have used and then edit your question as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  station_name,
  routes,
  ridership_2013,
  ridership_2014,
  ridership_2014 - ridership_2013 AS change_2013_raw,
  ROUND(((ridership_2014 - ridership_2013)/ ridership_2013)*100, 2) AS Percent_Change,
FROM
  bigquery-public-data.new_york_subway.subway_ridership_2013_present
WHERE
  ridership_2013 <>0 OR ridership_2014 <>0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to round the value in "percent_change", than you need to include your whole calculation in the ROUND() function.

For your calculation this will look as follows:

```
ROUND(((ridership_2014 - ridership_2013)/ ridership_2013) * 100, 2) AS Percent_Change
```

So in your query that looks like this:

```
SELECT station_name
, routes
, ridership_2013
, ridership_2014
, ridership_2014 - ridership_2013 AS change_2013_raw
, ROUND(((ridership_2014 - ridership_2013)/ ridership_2013) * 100, 2) AS Percent_Change
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_subway.subway_ridership_2013_present 
WHERE ridership_2013 <> 0 
OR ridership_2014 <> 0
```

For more information on the ROUND() function, see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_round.asp